# Background Image - how to scale properly with just css

Tags: css, html

I have this site in development, http://melanie.3drexstaging.com/
The client wants the background to scale up or down (to a point) depending on the browser size.
I have gotten it to work halfway decent with some jquery hacks to adjust sizing of elements as the browser resizes, but I would much prefer a css only option.
We have 3 images, one is the fixed aspect ratio center image that should always show in entirety, and to the left and right we have the images that continue the pattern.

Thanks in advance for any tips!

My SAD javascript hacks:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        fixBg();
    });
    $(window).load(function () {
        fixBg();
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
        fixBg();
    });
    function fixBg()
    {
        var mh = Math.max($(window).height(), 768);
        if ($("#ControlBar").length > 0) {
            mh -= 54;
        }
        var mw = Math.round((mh / 768) * 1264);
        var winW = Math.max(1264, $(window).width());
        $("#bgCenter").height(mh).width(mw);
        $("#shade").height(mh).width(mw).css("left", ((winW - mw) / 2) + 10);
        var extra = ((winW - mw) / 2) + 10;
        $(".bgFillers").width(extra).height(mh);
        var bgw = (mh / 768) * 360;
        $(".bgFillers").css("background-size", bgw + "px " + mh + "px");
        //$("#siteContent").css("min-height", mh - $("#header").height() - $("#footer").height() - 20);
    }
</script>
```

And the basic markup:

```
<div id="master">
    <div id="bg">
        <div id="bgLeft" class="bgs bgFillers"></div>
        <div id="bgCenter" class="bgs">
        </div>
        <div id="bgRight" class="bgs bgFillers"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="shade"></div>
    <div id="centeredSite">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you try cover? http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: that would be great if it was 1 image, but i have 3 images, the center one is not repeated, and to the left and right are the repeated images.

Comment: can't you just make one image out of all three and use that. i dont see why you need three images

Comment: off topic: @btevfik thanks for providing a link to that page

Answer (score 0):

have you tried making the size relative?

you just use % instead of px (or any other option)

100% is full element, 50% is half your element (if you put it in a div you set to 50% it'll take half of the div that's taking up half of your page, so 1/4th of your page)

otherwise i'll need some more information

Comment: this would normally work, but in my case, for example the entire browser is 1500 pixels wide by 900 and the middle image has an aspect ratio of 4:3, the middle image will be centered and will be 1200x900 to fit the height, leaving the 150 pixels of space on the left and right, the left side will need to be filled in by my left repeating image and the right side by mu right repeating image.  If you examine my link you will see that it is 3 different images.